# How to prevent a globally overridden "new" operator from being linked in from external library

Tags: c++, iphone, xcode, linker, new-operator

In our iPhone XCode 3.2.1 project, we're linking in 2 external static C++ libraries, libBlue.a and libGreen.a. libBlue.a globally overrides the "*new*" operator for it's own memory management. However, when we build our project, libGreen.a winds up using libBlue's *new* operator, which results in a crash (presumably because libBlue.a is making assumptions about the kinds of structures being allocated). Both libBlue.a and libGreen.a are provided by 3rd parties, so we can't change any of their source code or build options.

When we remove libBlue.a from the project, libGreen.a doesn't have any issues. However, no amount of shuffling the linking order of the libraries seems to fix the problem, nor does any experimentation with the various linking flags. Is there some way to tell XCode to tell the linker to "have libGreen's use of the *new* operator use the standard C++ *new* operator rather than the one redefined by libBlue"?

Comment: Sorry if "XCode" implies the answer, but for the rest of us -- can you state what platform and compiler/linker you're using?

Comment: XCode implies MacOSX, with XCode's compiler/linker (whose proper name I don't know).

Comment: XCode is the IDE for Mac OS X, and is a front-end for GCC (specifically, on my system, i686-apple-darwin10-gcc-4.2.1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps you could investigate using [GNU objcopy](http://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/binutils/objcopy.html), something along the lines of `objcopy --redefine-sym oldNew=newNew libBlue.a`.  The biggest problem I see with this is that Apple's developer tool suite doesn't seem to include objcopy.  You can install objcopy from [MacPorts](http://www.macports.org/) (`sudo port install binutils`), but that objcopy probably can't manipulate ARM object files.  There are a couple of ARM binutils in MacPorts, and I'm guessing `arm-elf-binutils` is your best bet.

Barring that, you could possibly disassemble libBlue.a, rename its new operator with a `sed` script, then reassemble it.  Perhaps you could even manipulate the libBlue.a symbol table directly.

Comment: I was able to use the "nmedit" utility to do pretty much the same thing by hiding the symbols. I made an "unexport.sym" file containing the symbols listed at http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/technotes/tn2007/tn2185.html#TNTAG7 and then ran:

nmedit -R unexport.sym libBlue.o -o libBlue-hideen-operators.o

That seems to have done the trick!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this will work, but you can try overriding *new* locally in your code. In your implementation, you can copy/paste the implementation of the standard *new* operator. When you need to create a *new* object in your code, call your *new* instead of the global *new* that libBlue has overridden. Then find the author of libBlue and give him a piece of your mind.

Check out http://www.informit.com/guides/content.aspx?g=cplusplus&seqNum=40 for a better summary than I can hope to provide.

Edit: Do you mean that code within libGreen.a will call *new* from libBlue, or do you mean your code creates a "*new* ClassDefinedInLibGreen( ... )" and ends up using libBlue's *new* operator? The solution I posted (if it even works) would only work for the latter case, since you don't have access to the source for either third-party library to control operator overrides.

Comment: Unfortunately, code in libGreen.a is calling new, which winds up calling libBlue.a's new method.

Answer (score 0):

You could isolate libBlue.a and libGreen.a in a separate process effectively creating a server which allows access to the encapsulated functionality through some form of interprocess communication.  This clearly has performance implications but solves the global namespace pollution problem.

Comment: Sadly, this is a client application which I can't break into multiple processes.

Answer (score 0):

There can be non-technical solutions:

1. It may be possible to extract functionality, provided by libBlue to separate application.
2. You can contact support of libBlue. Other people could also have the problem.
3. Find alternative.

P.S. It is strange, if developers if libBlue did some "smart" thing, without understanding how to fix problem they introduced.

Answer (score 0):

binary editing of the libraries?  If the interweb is to be trusted, it is in [Mach-O format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mach-O). See [this reference](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/MachORuntime/Reference/reference.html) for details.

libBlue.a must include a list of exported symbols.  Try renaming its "new" to "neo" or something.  libBlue should still be internally consistent, but libGreen will now only find the system "new" when linking.

Or alternately, libGreen.a must include a list of unresolved symbols, including "new", probably in a `__DATA,__la_symbol_ptr` section.  You could replace the instances of "new" with the name of a wrapper function defined in your app that performs same work.  (maybe even calling new directly, but that might end up back in libBlue.)