# C++ move/remove symbol

Tags: c++, c++11

Suppose I have a `.cpp` file in which I have to include a third-party header file that declares some symbol (let's call it `div`). I do not need this symbol, but I need to define my own `div` symbol. However, the original symbol might be used by some other part of the header file. Is it possible to remove the symbol from global namespace (something similar to `undef`ing a macro)?

I want something like this:

```
#include <string> //stdlib.h defines div symbol
//do some symbol removal magic here
std::string div;
```

to compile using gcc-4.7/clang with `-std=c++11` option.

Comment: Why not declare names in your lib in a namespace?

Comment: Because then I would have to qualify it with namespace name every time and I would prefer to avoid that.

Comment: Is there a reason other than laziness why you don't want to use a namespace?

Comment: No. But come on, all developers are lazy. That's why we have "using namespace nsname;" constructs in basically all sane languages.

Comment: And that laziness is probably the reason your 3rd party header pollutes the global namespace....

Comment: I am equally disgusted that C++ standard in 2011 revision was changed the way it was and now stdlib pollutes the global namespace. But I guess we have to live with it.

Comment: @TomaszGrobelny, can you explain the 'stdlib pollutes the global namespace' bit? I am not sure if anything in C++11 has done anything to do that.

Comment: So your objection is that you can't pollute the global namespace with your names because the standard library has already done it. Sorry, very little sympathy here. <g> Use a namespace; that's what they're for.

Comment: @Pete Becker: I would gladly put my symbol into my own namespace as long as the user is able to write "using namespace customNS;" and then use the symbols without qualifying with namespace name.

Comment: @Vikas: have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13040139/namespace-issues-in-c11

Comment: @TomaszGrobelny: "*then use the symbols without qualifying with namespace name.*" That's not how namespaces work, nor is that what they are *for*. If you dump namespace symbols into the global namespace to use it, *you're doing it wrong*.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Basically, **no**.

But as the others say you can use a namespace instead to get the same effect with what is actually essentially a completely different symbol.

Answer (score 8):

You cannot remove a symbol from the namespace in which it was defined (including the global namespace).

Wrap your own `div` in your own namespace.

Comment: Wrapping my symbol in a namespace does not remove the previous definition from global namespace.

Answer (score 1):

I've never used it, but you can try with [GNU objcopy](http://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/binutils/objcopy.html) (as suggested in https://stackoverflow.com/a/1950629/721929).

But I think it's something to avoid if you have control on source code. It will be time expensive to test if this works.

```
--redefine-sym old=new
Change the name of a symbol old, to new. This can be useful when one is 
trying link two things together for which you have no source, 
and there are name collisions. 

objcopy --redefine-sym oldNew=newNew libBlue.a
```